# use overlap2d in libgdx has some wrong, can not fill the screen.why?

Tags: android, libgdx, overlap2d

I use the 0.1.1 version of overlap2d. and can not fill my screen. here is my code:

```
mSceneLoader = new SceneLoader();
mSceneLoader.loadScene("MainScene", new StretchViewport(480, 800));
```

and in the render meathod:

```
mSceneLoader.getEngine().update(delta);
```

And when I run on my note4.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewport should probably have WORLD units rather than pixels. You can probably check that in the overlap2d editor.

I think it is shown in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhvHm2sM0qo

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try FillViewport ? it does what FitViewport does but fills the screen.

Is this ran on android or desktop? or rather, what is the actual screen size in pixels? (what it outputs when you output Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() ) ?

Other thing is, to understand viewports better, take a look at this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use the FitViewport, it can also not work normal. I run on android, desktop, iOS, It also like the picture up.   I am crazy...